# ¿Que realiza exactamente la siguiente sentencia return?

Tags: c

```
    return *s && strchr(delimiter, *s);
```

He visto que es usada en javascript como una abreviación de:

```
       if(param 1) return param2;
        else return param1;
```

Pero no me queda claro si su uso es igual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Son 4 partes, bien diferenciadas:

```
*s
```

Obten el valor al que apunta el puntero `s`.

```
&&
```

Si el valor anterior **no es 0**, continua

```
strchr( delimiter, *s );
```

Obten el valor de la llamada a esta función (que, dicho sea de paso, busca un caracter en un *arreglo* de ellos, apuntado por la variable `delimiter`. El caracter está apuntado por `s`).

```
return
```

Devuelve el resultado de todo lo anterior. En otras palabras:

```
if( *s ) {
  return strchr( delimiter, *s );
} else {
  return *s;
}
```

Que también se podría escribir como

```
return *s ? strchr( delimiter, *s ) : *s;
```

o

```
return *s ? strchr( delimiter, *s ) : 0;
```

Si bien yo usaría este última forma.

Como ves, es lo mismo que para Javascript.